macbook runs something when closed
Macbook Pro, 2019, macOS Monterey.
When done, I usually close my macbook and we both go to sleep. Recently I noticed that something is running on the closed macbook, heating it and draining the battery. I have a bunch of tabs on Chrome and Safari, but it has never been a problem before. How do I diagnose what's running on my macbook in the middle of the night?

Run pmset -g everything. In the resulting log, find the timestamps corresponding to shortly before your expected sleep to shortly after your attempted wake. Upload those log entries to a site like www.PasteBin.com and update your question with a link to that log and we can look to see what’s taking a sleep assertion and preventing sleep.
